# how to access values in javascript's object?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to iterate through the values in an object.

Here are the values of the object:

```js
object=Object.values(localStorage)[0];
console.log(object);
```

### Output

```js
{"name":"e7","id":"7","category":"n"}
```

I tried:

```js
console.log(object[0]);
```

But it printed just `"{"`... Then I tried... `object[name], object['name'] , object[0][0]`... but the output is not satisfactory...

I want to loop through these values like I want to access "name" and its value and so on...

Can I loop through individual values of JavaScript?

the output is actually a value ..

Comment: You don't actually have an object, but a string. It's serialised JSON. You need to `JSON.parse` it to produce an actual object. Then you can get its values using `Object.values` just like before.

Comment: LocalStorage can only store strings, not objects directly.

Comment: "the output is not satisfactory" is not a satisfactory problem description.

Comment: Try typeof to see what is happening

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting and getting object to local storage using stringify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12051357/setting-and-getting-object-to-local-storage-using-stringify)

Comment: by writing "r=JSON.parse(m[0]) " and then" r.name" i get value of name (key)... how can i get key by mentioning value?

Answer (score 1):

[Local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) can only store strings, so what you get from it is just a JSON string and you have to parse it into a JavaScript object before you can use it like one.

> The keys and the values are **always strings** (note that, as with objects, integer keys will be automatically converted to strings).

You can do it by calling `JSON.parse()` (documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)).

```js
var fromLocalStorage = '{"name":"e7","id":"7","category":"n"}';

// Parse the JSON string from localStorage into a JS object
var object = JSON.parse(fromLocalStorage);

// Get a single property
console.log(object.name);

// Loop all the key-value pairs of the object
Object.keys(object).forEach(function(key) {
    console.log(key + ' -> ' + object[key]);
});
```